# Combinations without repetition of a matrix

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix, combinations

I have a matrix contained in a two-dimensional array.

```
int[][] combinationValues
```

This array can vary in size, however using the test cases I have right now its maximum size has been 6 by 6.

This matrix is a set of non-distinct integers, an example value would be...

```
[1][1,2,3]
[2][4,5,6]
[3][7,8,9]
```

I'm looking to obtain an array/list of all of the combinations of these values without repetitions, taking only one value from each row. So using the previous example value, the result would be...

```
[1,5,9] , [1,6,8] , [2,4,9] , [2,7,6] , [3,4,8] , [3,5,7]
```

So the following results would not be correct.

```
[1,4,7] //three from the first row
[1,5,8] //two from the second row
```

If you can help me, pseudocode is very welcome, however I am currently using Java for my implementation.

Comment: I've looked around and recursion appears to be popular. However, I'm inexperienced with it and I have trouble getting my head around how it could work.

Comment: Are [1,4,7] and [1,7,4] a repetition?

Comment: I may be using the wrong words to describe what I want here. Each combination needs to take one element from a different row.

Comment: So both [1,4,7] and [1,7,4] would not be correct results, and neither would [2,5,8] [3,6,9] or [2,6,9]

Comment: You don't really mean *duplicate* elements but *element from an index already used* e.g. [1, 4, x] cannot be an option since 1 and 4 are in the same index in each array.

Comment: Yeah. In regards to the term duplication I think I mean less duplicate elements and more duplicate results, however I suspect duplicate results isn't a problem that needs to be considered.

Answer (score 1):

This is a basic idea to solve the problem:

- Use an array (or another collection) that will store the indexes that are used (the *duplicates*)
- For 0 to the last possible index available:

  - Check if the index is already marked as *duplicate*
  - If it's a duplicate, then move to the next index
  - If it's not a duplicate, then

    - Go to the next possible array
    - Get the element at that index
    - Add the index to the array (or collection) to mark it as *duplicate*
    - Repeat this same process in the for for the available arrays
    - Remove the index to the array (or collection) to unmark it as *duplicate*

Answer (score 1):

So you want one element by row and by column ? Simply combinatory analyze says that you should get `n!` solutions.

You can easily backtrack in java or any other language that can dynamically append to lists

Pseudo-code :

```
void test(List<List<Integer>> matrix, int row, int column, List<List<Integer>> results,
        List<Integer> current, List<Integer> used)
    // tries to add a new value to current result
    if used does not contain j {
        add matrix[i][j] to list current
        add j to list used
        if i is last row (i == matrix.size() -1) {
            add result to list results
        }
        else {         // processes next row
            for(int k=0, k<matrix[0].size(); k++) {
                test(matrix, i+1, k, results, current, used)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Main code :

```
List<List<Integer>> results = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(); // initializes results
for (i=0; i<matrix[0].size(); i++) {  // try each element of first line
    test(matrix, 0, i, results, new ArrayList<Integer>(), new ArrayList<Integer>())
}
```